# CSS Div Inline-Block vertical-align top

Tags: css

[image]

I have div that the display is inline-block (CSS).

```css
    #content {
      position: absolute;
      width: 950px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    #content .post_box {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 300px;
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      vertical-align: top;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #content .post_box img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="post_box">
    a
  </div>

  <div class="post_box">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CdRFUqRVAAAtREu.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="post_box">
    c
  </div>

  <div class="post_box">
    d
    <br>d
  </div>

  <div class="post_box">
    e
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the demo:

http://175.111.116.69/kongkow.co/

I want "d" is exactly under "a". So "d" will be the left of that image.

How can I fix that code?

Comment: your question is not clear. Can you explain it with details or provide a rough sketch of what you want?

Comment: Explain it in detail with a rough sketch.

Comment: Please have a look on image above. Just updated. It's like twitter home page(before login).

Comment: Basically you have three columns - wrap content of each column in a div and apply property `float: left`, you will achieve your result.

Comment: You can try `#content .post_box{vertical-align: bottom; }` everything would be bottom of the image.

Answer (score 2):

This Might Help you

```
 <div id="content">
  <div class="post_box">
      <div class="post_box">
        a
     </div>
     <div class="post_box">
        d<br>d
     </div>
     <div class="post_box">
        e
     </div>
  </div>

     <div class="post_box">
        <img src=""/>
    </div>
  <div class="post_box">
    <div class="post_box">
        c
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why you are not using css property `float: left`, I think it will also work